# Are there any core invariants to Hinduism?

Tags: belief, culture

From what I've seen, Hinduism isn't a religion like most of the other modern ones with many "rules" that you have to follow, it's more of a "pick-your-own-rules" way of doing it. (See: [Is there an Orthodox Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-there-an-orthodox-hinduism))

Additionally, it changes much as time passes<sup>1</sup>

The question is, are there any invariant "core" tenets/rules to Hinduism; i.e. rules that have not changed since Vedic times and are still a part of the religion.

Some candidates:

- The no-conversions rule (one must be born a Hindu). This seems to be changing now.
- Restrictions against beef

<sup>1. So do other religions, really.</sup>

Comment: The freedom to seek **your** truth or God or form is the invariant. This freedom was not denied to Arjuna by Krishna.

Comment: " Hinduism isn't a religion like most of the other modern ones with many "rules" that you have to follow, it's more of a "pick-your-own-rules" way of doing it" - Incorrect.  " it changes much as time passes" - Also incorrect. Good Q though.

Comment: no-conversion rule is myth.
I have added "many details" about devalasmriti scripture in my answer at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 . see "argument 3" in my answer . You may check "argument 1" also

Answer (score 7):

Some core invariants IMHO,

1. Belief in Veda/Shruti (this is summarily rejected by Cārvāka and other materialistic and atheistic school of Hinduism).
2. Belief in Re-incarnation
3. Belief in [Atman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_(Hinduism))
4. Belief in One universal [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman) which pervades all beings, animate as well as inanimate.
5. Belief in Karma and the role it play

Comment: Not just first, but all of the first three are rejected by materialistic school of Hinduism. I'm not sure about 4 and 5.

Comment: Nastika schools aren't really "Hinduism" though. Also, I believe point 5 is cultural rather than religious (that is, it is taken as given and Astika philosophies are a response to this presumption), but perhaps I am wrong