# Can anybody identify them as Hindu? or there is a mandatory conversion procedure from a religious body?

Tags: conversion

Namastee

Suppose person X want to take Hinduism. Can they just identify as Hindus and start to participate in Hindu festivals etc? or it is mandatory have a conversion from a religious body?

Additional question - if the person X don't like the new way of faith, can he or she quit Hinduism upto a certain point of time?

Comment: Are you asking same question as this one: [Is it true one can not convert to Hinduism from any religion and vice versa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/407/647)

Comment: No it is a different question. Can anybody identify themselve as Hindus? or they needs to consult to a religious body?

Comment: Just go through all the answers in above link. I think most of the answers are answering your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that one can not convert to Hinduism from any other religion or vice versa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/407/is-it-true-that-one-can-not-convert-to-hinduism-from-any-other-religion-or-vice)