# How Does Hindu Dharma Differ from Other Religions?

Tags: gods, dharma, other-religions, vedic-gods

There are so many religions and every religion believes that there is some God.
There are good people who want to do good Karma. Why is the need for so many religions and why isn’t there only one Dharma, when everybody believes there is only one Bhagwan (God)?

Comment: you have at least 3 questions here. limit your questions to 1 question at a time. see forum rules.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda thanks for informing about it. Acually I don't know about such rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any core invariants to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/118/are-there-any-core-invariants-to-hinduism)

Comment: @sv. I don't know how you find this question duplicate of what you have mentioned. I request you to read and feel the depth of the question and Answer both. I will be blessed.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in the body of the question but the question in the tile seems like a duplicate of the other.

Comment: "feel the depth of the question and Answer both" - I 'felt' both of them 'deeply' and both your Q and A seems a better fit for a blog. But this is a Q&A site. Self-answering is encouraged provided the question is accepted by the community.

Comment: @sv. Ok go ahead. Feel happy in deleting the post. By the way there are different different way of answering questions. If you feel that it is not up to the mark then do your job.

Comment: @sv. Both the things are same in body and title. But in a different way. Meaning are same of both the things.

Comment: "Why is the need for so many religions and why isn’t there only one Dharma" - this is better suited for [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) or [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @sv. sad! If you read the answer sincerely, you will never suggest so. There is only one dharma. Don't misinterpret dharma as religion. So chill!. there is nothing wrong in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92060/discussion-between-sumit-sharma-and-sv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please note that this answer is not the author's own:** This answer is a direct English translation of Shri Jagannath Puri Shankaracharya ji's answer to a similiar question. He answers the question in Hindi in this link [How Does Hindu Dharma Differ from Other Religions?](https://youtu.be/ogb8GQnO21U)
Editing this answer so that due credit and proper reference can be provided to the response.

#### What is Dharma?

First thing is, **Is the word ‘Dharma’ used in the Bible?...or is it used in the Quran Sharif?** Secondly, don’t we know the name, age and period of the creator these religions? These are creations of mind of a particular person/s and we call their created religion as ‘Dharma’ only due to our own magnanimity. If we apply the principles of Dharma, do they qualify as Dharma, this is what we need to ponder upon.

It is due to our magnanimity, we call these sects, their beliefs, their theories as Dharma.
If we apply the actual definition of Dharma... do these qualify as Dharma? In English, they would call it ‘Religion’ only.

> Dharma can’t be translated as religion anyways.
>   The sense in which word Dharma has been used in Vedic literature.
>
> > Jains and Buddhists may not consider themselves as Vedic, but they have taken the word Dharma from the Vedas only. They have taken ‘Omkar’ from Vedas only.
> >
> > > If we were to call a drop of water as Ocean or if a spark of fire as fire, there is a lot of difference. That’s why, the way we define Dharma, all these stand nowhere near it.

One of my Guru's disciple in Vrindavan used to lie a lot. His father was in the Police force. Guruji told his disciple's father that the son lies a lot, the father agreed and said he himself too feds up of his lies. Guruji told him it will be good if his son does LLB (Law). The disciple was already a "Masters in History" and father said, he will teach him law himself. Guruji thought that he was not an LLB and in fact didn’t study after Intermediate. His father said that "I arrest people under particular sections of a particular law”. Person who think that he knows Law because he can charge somebody by the rules of that Law is a fool.

> > In the same way, if a particular stream of waterbody like Gangnahar, went somewhere, it does not become that river. We should search the origin of that stream.
> >
> > > Like that, all the Religions are born from the Sanatan Dharma.

---

10th Mandala of Rigveda which is the 'Nasadiya Suktam' talks about Absolute Dharma:

> Nasadiya Suktam has only 7 mantras and scientists world over are still engrossed into these as in that nature of the universe is explained in those seven mantras, no scientists can ever negate this and in fact is bound to follow that.
>
> > **So, what I have said is that any stream of Dharma due to which humanity somehow survives, if it reaches somewhere, it doesn’t mean that it is absolute Dharma. The whole Dharma is Vedic Dharma only which is the oldest.**

---

#### Let’s talk about other thing i.e. Ishwara (God)

In one and other Ishwara, there could be difference of earth and sky.
You would be amazed to know that there is a difference in two Ishwara itself and there could be wicked Ishwara as well.

**The Ishwara created out of the imagination of a human is not an Ishwara.
Babas (Spiritual Gurus) is also being called Ishwara today.**

> **Bhamti Kar Vachaspati Mishra ji** has used a word, 'Vidur prabhavit kanta sakshatkar'( विदुर प्रभावित कांता साक्षात्कार ). Vidhur is a person whose wife has died.
>   If he meditates about this wife in his imagination and due to the strength of his feelings, he can have a glimpse and can even be able to touch her. This is called “Vidur prabhavit Kanta Sakshatkar” ( विदुर प्रभावित कांता साक्षात्कार ) by Bhamtikar Vachaspati Mishra Ji. But this is not real.
>
> > In the same way, there are many kinds of Ishwara. If any Ishwara is created with the imagination of emotional people, that is not real Ishwara as it doesn’t have the traits of Ishwara.

Similarly, if a person believes in an Ishwara only due to his inference, then too that Ishwara is not real Ishwara. Why not? The imaginary Ishwara born out of the sentiments of an emotional person can not become real Ishwara. It is like the emotional person who saw his dead wife in his dream world.

---

**Neither is the Ishwara proven with the power of inference of such logic can not be proved to be the true Ishwara.**

> Once I told someone the same thing. He didn’t say anything that moment, but later said, “I have been a lawyer...do pardon me, I didn’t like this argument of yours that any Ishwara proved with the power of inference of logician, is not Ishwara. I disagree with this. The inference should be the proof.” I said, “Not at all.”
>
> > I explained to him — when will logic prevail by giving reference from the **Shankara Bhasya on Kena Upanishad**. At a far off place, we see smoke on a hill so from that we infer that there must be fire there. So, is the fire there proved with inference, is able to remove darkness or cold here? No!.
> >     This is a very good example. So, any Ishwara proved with the power of inference, that is not real Ishwara but only flights of fancy!

Naiyayikas (Scientists) and Vaishashikas (Buddhists, only believe in realisation) too have considered the form of Ishwar but that is not real Ishwar. Their Ishwara is not existence but exist because of the existence in general, not consciousness, but conscious because of one of the attributes of the consciousness called Gyan, not blissfulness either.

> Similarly, the Ishwara which can create the cosmos but cannot become the cosmos, i.e. can be a maker but not the matter, for that, I will ask a rhetorical question.
>
> > Another small thing which everybody can understand that any knowledgeable, desire-driven, active and conscious person creates the instrument microphone through metal and plastic, he will have the ability to make the microphone but not himself becoming the microphone.
> >     And the matter, i.e. plastic and metal which went into making of this microphone, had the ability to become a microphone but not to be the maker of that microphone.
> >
> > > Any mechanic, no matter how good he is, can we say that he has full control over the instrument that he has made? No. And if he does not have full control over that, how come he is Ishwara. That’s why the Ishwara accepted in Vedas is true.

We have the criteria to judge the Ishwara and one who is maker as well as matter that only has all the traits of Ishwara.
That’s why they have makeshift Ishwaras and in truth, the traits of Ishwara are present in Vedas only. And the Dharma approved by the Vedas only qualifies to be Dharma

> According to Sut-samhita, what we have told about this mechanic thing, according to our **Guruji Swami Karpatri ji Maharaj**, his commentary on *Ishavasya Upanishad*,
>
> Those whose Ishwara can create the cosmos but can’t become the cosmos, their Ishwara, can’t have full control over the cosmos and when he has no control over the cosmos, so it means, it has no traits of Ishwara. In reality, their Ishwara can not even make the Universe.
>
> One more thing, those whose Ishwara can create the cosmos and can become the cosmos, their Ishwara only can take incarnation. Whose Ishwara can create the cosmos but can’t become the cosmos, it cannot take incarnation.

**For example,** the Ishwara of Vaishashiks, Nyayikas and of Seshwar Sakhyavadi Yogis can’t take incarnation.

Let me give an example, there is this word ‘Aabhas’ (impression).

**Chitabhas** mean - that which looks like conscious like Chit but not has the traits of consciousness,

**DharmAbhas** would be – which seems like Dharma but has no traits of dharma,

**IshwarAbhas** would be – which seems like Ishwara but has no traits of Ishwara.

**At other places, it is DharmAbhas and IshwarAbhas, so there is only one Dharma and Ishwara. The dharma which is described in Veda only is dharma.**

*Any of its stream, went here and there, that is not Dharma. They are right up to that extent which is acceptable to the root of Dharma.*

Comment: "2. Why Veda, Upanishads and Gita is superior to Bible, Quran and any other book or theory in the world?" - I don't see this in the question....

Comment: @sv. Clearly mentioned that only 7 solakas are enough for their supremacy.

Comment: No, @SumitSharma he means when the Q isn't asking for it why have you included that in the answer?

Comment: @Rickross First I explain the meaning Dharma and Religion as these two words came in Q. Then I proved the authenticity and supremacy of the holy book as they are the base of Dharma. And then I presented why is there differences in Gods itself. And in the last I gave the qualities of God which is described by the Vedas and Vedas are only, which is supreme, should everyone follow then only Dharma will be established.

Comment: "Thou shall promote no God". This is a site's motto. This is not for proving superiority of Hinduism over other religions. Read [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/5212). I think you have to remove that portion which talks about superiority of religions. Also cite some sources for other parts of the answer. Personal experiences are not considered as sources here.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma did you see any promotion of any God? I didn't. I just wrote about traits (guna) of God and illusions what people have. Personal Experiences?? I myself wrote which demolishing personal experiences in my answer. I gave my answer on the logic and quoted the scriptures and person also. And now if you say that logic is not allowed then I will say the only thing is that Read it first with open mind keeping your rules aside and then judge. if you find good then kindly upvote my answer.

Comment: Second portion here in the answer "Why Veda, Upanishads and Gita..."  this is irrelevant portion in the answer. This shows that Hinduism is superior to other religions. This also uses science to prove Vedas are right. Using science to explain something is not allowed here. Scientific speculation is off-topic. In the first part of the answer, you quoted something but what was the basis for those quotes? When you quote something, you should show where you have taken those. You used some personal experiences of your guru's disciple and Mr.Bush. Those are not considered valid sources here.